# Semaphore CI - Environment Variables are Incorrect

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, environment-variables, semaphore-ci

I use [`semaphore CI`](https://docs.semaphoreci.com/) for continuous integration, specifically for Feature tests and Specs in PHP and Ruby. I noticed a deviation from the documentation on caching in one of my projects. The documentation says:

> The `cache restore` command that has zero arguments would lookup cachable elements and try to fetch them from the repository.

```
$ cache restore
==> Detecting project structure and storing it into the cache.

* Detected Gemfile.lock.
* Fetching 'vendor/bundle' directory with cache keys 'gems-your-branch-checksum,gems-master-,gems-your-branch-'.
...
```

The important part about that is the 3 cache keys:

> `gems-your-branch-checksum`
> `gems-master-`
> `gems-your-branch-`

When I implemented the `cache restore` command and ran the job, this was the output I got:

```
* Detected Gemfile.lock.
* Fetching 'vendor/bundle' directory with cache keys 'gems-master-checksum,gems-master-,gems-master-'.
...
```

**This job was not run against `master`, but a different branch, let's call it `secondary`.** Notice the slight deviation on the branches:

> `gems-master-checksum` (expected this to be `gems-secondary-checksum`)
> `gems-master-` (this one is expected)
> `gems-master-` (expected this to be `gems-secondary`)

For some reason, Semaphore thinks that my branch is `master`, not secondary. I did some more digging. You can manually specify Cache Keys using the following syntax:

```
cache restore gems-$SEMAPHORE_GIT_BRANCH-$(checksum Gemfile.lock)
```

But, when running this, it outputs

> `gems-master-checksum` (expected `gems-secondary-checksum`)

I was able to eventually get it working with the other environment variable:

```
cache restore gems-$SEMAPHORE_GIT_PR_BRANCH-$(checksum Gemfile.lock)
```

> `gems-secondary-checksum`

The [documentation](https://docs.semaphoreci.com/ci-cd-environment/environment-variables) suggests that this shouldn't be the case:

> SEMAPHORE_GIT_BRANCH
> The value of the SEMAPHORE_GIT_BRANCH environment variable is the name of the GitHub branch that is used in the current job.
> In builds triggered by a Pull Request the value of the SEMAPHORE_GIT_BRANCH is the name of the GitHub branch targeted by the Pull Request.
> SEMAPHORE_GIT_PR_BRANCH
> The value of the SEMAPHORE_GIT_PR_BRANCH environment variable is the name of the GitHub branch from which the Pull Request originated.

Has anyone seen this issue with Semaphore CI? It's not a critical issue, as there are workarounds, but I'm thinking there is an issue with my configuration somewhere, but I can't seem to find anything useful/related.